# Discord python, if/else in on_raw_reaction_add dont work

Tags: python, discord

When I react to a message for the first time it works, but the next time nothing happens (loop_one is still True). Does anyone know why this is happening?

````
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
global loop_one
if payload.emoji.name == '':
    await last_message.remove_reaction('', payload.member)
    if loop_one == True:
        loop_one = False
    else:
        loop_one = True```
````

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fixed it, just do this:

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
global loop_one
if payload.emoji.name == '':
    await last_message.remove_reaction('', payload.member)
    loop_one = not loop_one
```